# uib-dropdown outsideClick is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

When I define auto-close to outsideClick the dropdown closes in all cases even when I select an element.

```
<div class="v3-multiselect" uib-dropdown ng-cloak auto-close="outsideClick" is-open="isOpen">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle v3-multiselect-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle>
  <b>{{ optionLabel }}:</b> Max {{ max }}
  </a>
  <span class="v3-caret-more pull-right"></span>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu">
 <li  ng-click="toggleOption(option['id']); " ng-repeat="option in opt ions track by option['id']" class="v3-multiselect-option" ng-class="{checked: isChecked(option['id'])}">
     <label>{{ option.name }}</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you define auto-close ? It is default behavior to close dropdown when clicked outside. Try removing it and it should work fine.